# generate a sequence of correlated numbers from a given sequence of numbers from unknown distribution

Tags: random, sequence

How can I generate a sequence of correlated numbers from a given sequence of numbers from unknown distribution? i.e., not normal.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using an [AR (auto-regressive) model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregression#Example%3a_An_AR.281.29_process).  I prefer the following formulation for the AR(1), which is a slightly different formulation than in the Wikipedia article:

```
X(t) = mu + rho * (X(t-1) - mu) + epsilon(t)
```

where the `epsilon`'s are independent and identically distributed random variates with any marginal distribution you like as long as it has a mean of zero and finite variance. With this formulation, the mean of the AR is `mu` and the correlation at lag 1 is `rho`.  The correlation structure dies off geometrically as the lag increases.

If `R` is a random variable with your desired marginal distribution, but `E[R]` is non-zero, you can always re-center it to a get zero-mean epsilon:

```
epsilon(t) = R(t) - E[R]
```

Pick a random starting value for `X(0)` such that `E[X(0)] = mu` and `Var(X(0)) = Var(epsilon)/(1 - rho^2)`, and then iterate to get as many `X`'s as you need.